# gitlab pipeline with embedded mongodb

Tags: mongodb, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to build a pipeline for a gradle java app which is using an embedded mongo instance. I have built a container to which has java and mongo. However, I keep getting the following error for all my test that require the embedded mongo instance.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedMongoServer' 
defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/embedded/EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: 
Cannot run program "/tmp/extract-f816c11c-614b-46d7-ad29-68923ca9d624extractmongod": error=2, No such file or directory
```

My `gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```
image: java:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: gitlab-ci

stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  script: ./gradlew --build-cache assemble
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    policy: push
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle

test:
  stage: test
  image: registry.gitlab.com/path/to/explorer-ci:1.0.0
  script: ./gradlew check --debug
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle
```

The build job works fine, the test job fails. My explorer-ci container is built using the following Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache \
        mongodb \
        bash

VOLUME /data/db
VOLUME log

RUN ["mongod", "--smallfiles", "--fork", "--logpath", "log/mongodb.log"]
```

I've spent a week with a bunch of different configs but can't seem to hack it. Just to note, builds/tests run fine on my local machine. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

On reflection, as I am using an embedded mongo instance, I do not have a dependency on mongodb to build or test. I am now using the following `gitlab-ci.yaml` and it works fine.

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: gitlab-ci

stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  script: ./gradlew --build-cache assemble
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    policy: push
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle

test:
  stage: test
  script: ./gradlew check
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was on base docker image for your project runner, You need to use jdk version not alpine.

Try to change base image to this `image: openjdk:8-jdk` and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In our case the solution described at Fladoodle embedded MongoDB on the issues here helped:

https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/issues/281

In short - we added this to our Gitlab script (or do this in container setup itself if possible) before running our tests:

```
    apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
wget -q -O /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub

wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.29-r0/glibc-2.29-r0.apk
wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.29-r0/glibc-bin-2.29-r0.apk

apk add glibc-2.29-r0.apk glibc-bin-2.29-r0.apk

wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.29-r0/glibc-i18n-2.29-r0.apk
apk add glibc-bin-2.29-r0.apk glibc-i18n-2.29-r0.apk
/usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score -1):

just updating the dependency should resolve:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```